# Item level permission not working for list with unique permission

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions, unique

I have a list with unique permissions. As a new item is created, with a flow, I delete all permissions (stop sharing) and assign new ones to some group using http call with roles assignment.
I realized I the edit permissions I am giving - despite correctly displayed - are not working. Even providing owner permissions works!
In this case LHDBOT01 has owner permissions (provided with the flow)
[image]
But when LHDBOT01 tries to modify this item...
[image]
He's getting this error message
[image]

Of course, I don't want to give this user edit access on list level...

Some suggestions?

Comment: Is user able to edit item using "Edit" button at the top (in list command bar)? What permissions are granted to user at "site" level?

Comment: Have you considered giving them Contribute access at list level? They can only read/write /delete items to the list then. Item level permissions are not great, particularly if the list is large.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, yes the button is there. But when saving, I am getting the error message

Comment: @CallumCrowley I have being trying all kind of permissions. View only works, all other having edit features, won't

Comment: I mean, give the users contribute permission on the list, not the list item. Delete unique permissions on the list item.

Comment: @CallumCrowley I have attempted and even like this I get the same result. BTW I don't want this user to be able to see all items

Comment: You may have accidentally deleted the "Limited Access" permission for the user maybe? You can grant them contribute to the list without them seeing all items: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized waht's the problem: I set up in the list settings/advanced settings/item level permissions "Create items and edit item that were..." rather than "Create and edit all items":
[image]
Once changed, all works as expected!